# Centos 7 two nics (local and internet) routing problems

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I'm having (or thinking!) a routing problem on a Centos7 server.

I have two network adapters, LocalNetwork: 192.168.0.1/22 and Internet: 189.x.x.x/28. On this server I have an ApacheServer that must respond to requests as much from the internet as from the local network. The problem is that the requests coming from the internet give an error (no response), since the requests of the local network are perfect. When I disconnect the local network the intenet requests work.

I think it's a route problem. It should have a rule something like this:

- if the request came from the local network interface, it must return through the local network interface;
- if the request came through the internet interface, must return through the internet interface;

Attention: I do not want to route between the two network interface!!!

Comment: What interfaces does your Apache bind to?

Comment: What you describe that you want is how it normally works. If it doesn't work that way, your server is misconfigured. Please include the output of `sudo ip route`, when both connections are configured, in your question.

Comment: I think you have two default routes. Disable default IP route on local network interface.

Comment: The ip route table:
`default via 192.168.1.22 dev ens160  proto static  metric 100`
`default via 189.X.X.X dev ens33  proto static  metric 101`
`189.X.X.X/28 dev ens33  proto kernel  scope link  src 189.3.20.62  metric 100`
`192.168.0.0/22 dev ens160  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.93  metric 100`

/etc/sysconfig/network is empty... no default route

ens160 (local) GW is 192.168.1.22 (the GW for all local network... is the FW)
ens33 (internet) GW is 189.X.X.Y where Y is the router of service provider.